# python code not working - adding odd numbers of an array

Tags: python

Im trying to write a function where it accepts the various arrays and adds the total of the odd numbers. Then if the total is correct it returns "TEST PASSED" but i cannot complete the code.
the code is:

```
def odd_ones(array):
  total = 0
  for i in range(0,len(array)-1):
    if array[i] % 2 != 0:
      total += array[i]
      print(total)
    else:
      print("no odd numbers detected")



def test_odd_ones():
  print("Odd Ones Unit Test...")
  print("")
  if odd_ones([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) == 25:
    print("TEST PASSED")
  else:
    print("TEST FAILED")
  if odd_ones([3,3,1,1,5,5]) == 18:
    print("TEST PASSED")
  else:
    print("TEST FAILED")
  if odd_ones([2,4,6,10,20]) == 0:
    print("TEST PASSED")
  else:
    print("TEST FAILED")
  if odd_ones([]) == "Empty Array":
    print("TEST PASSED")
  else:
    print("TEST FAIL
```

Comment: You should return `total` from `odd_ones`

Comment: you need to return total from the function

Comment: Also, `for i in range(0, len(array)-1):` ignores the last item in the list. You can use `for i in range(0, len(array)):` or `for i in range(len(array)):` or `for i in array:`

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use `range(0, len(array))` because range iterates upto n-1. You should return `total` from the function so that it can be used while calling the function.

```
def odd_ones(array):
  if len(array) == 0:
    return "Empty Array"
  total = 0
  for i in range(0,len(array)):
    if array[i] % 2 != 0:
      total += array[i]
  return total


def test_odd_ones():
  print("Odd Ones Unit Test...")
  print("")
  if odd_ones([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) == 25:
    print("TEST PASSED")
  else:
    print("TEST FAILED")
  if odd_ones([3,3,1,1,5,5]) == 18:
    print("TEST PASSED")
  else:
    print("TEST FAILED")
  if odd_ones([2,4,6,10,20]) == 0:
    print("TEST PASSED")
  else:
    print("TEST FAILED")
  if odd_ones([]) == "Empty Array":
    print("TEST PASSED")
  else:
    print("TEST FAILED")
```